# What is optimized way to validate mandatory fields based on other field value in Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, design-patterns

I am creating a spring boot rest application where i am getting player information as JSON in a POST request to persist into database. In total, we have 16 fields but in future more fields will be added.

```
{
    "jerseyNumber": "1",
    "firstName": "Sachin",
    "lastName": "Tendulkar",
    "age": "35",
    "country": "India",
    "playerType": "Batsmen",
    "score": "101",
    "ballsFaced": "110",
    "strikeRate": "90",
    "fours": "15",
    "sixes": "1",
    "oversBowled": "",    '
    "runsGiven": "",
    "maidenOvers": "",
    "wicketsTaken": "",
    "economy": ""
  }
```

if playerType = Batsmen, below 11 fields are mandatory, other fields specific to bowler can be null/empty.

```
{
    "jerseyNumber": "1",
    "firstName": "Sachin",
    "lastName": "Tendulkar",
    "age": "35",
    "country": "India",
    "playerType": "Batsmen",
    "score": "101",
    "ballsFaced": "110",
    "strikeRate": "90",
    "fours": "15",
    "sixes": "1",
  }
```

if playerType = Bowler, below 11 fields are mandatory.

```
{
    "jerseyNumber": "10",
    "firstName": "Zaheer",
    "lastName": "Khan",
    "age": "38",
    "country": "India",
    "playerType": "Bowler",
    "oversBowled": "10",    '
    "runsGiven": "39",
    "maidenOvers": "1",
    "wicketsTaken": "3",
    "economy": "3.9"
  }
```

Pojo Class

```
public class CricketPlayer {
 private String jerseyNumber;
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 private String age;
 private String country;
 private String playerType;
 private String score;
 private String ballsFaced;
 private String strikeRate;
 private String fours;
 private String sixes;
 private String oversBowled;
 private String runsGiven;
 private String maidenOvers;
 private String wicketsTaken;
 private String economy;


 // Getter Methods 
}
```

On receiving the request, i need to perform validation based on playerType value, 1) if all the mandatory fields are given (not empty or null) in the json request.

Also below business validations needs to be checked,

```
a) age => 18 and age <= 50
b) country is any value from (England, Australia, India, Srilanka, New Zealand, South Africa, Pakistan, Zimbabwe, West Indies, Bangladesh)
c) maidenOvers < oversBowled
d) wicketsTaken < 11
e) ballsfaced < =360
f) oversBowled <= 10
```

Going forward, the number of mandatory fields can increase to 25-30 fields. I can write the validation using if else statement based on player type value.

```
if(cricketPlayer.getPlayerType.equals("Batsmen")
{
// writelogic to check if all mandatory fields are not null or empty

} else if(cricketPlayer.getPlayerType.equals("Bowler")
{


}
```

But multiple if else block doesn't look good if we have more than 20-25 mandatory fields to validate. What is the optimized and best approach to follow in this scenario so that it is more readable and easy to add or remove any validations.

Comment: Looks like design is wrong from the beginning. read Separation of concerns.

Comment: @AbhirojPanwar: Since a bowler can also bat and vice-versa, i have taken all the fields in same json.

Comment: looks to me like other fields can be assigned default values for validation. u r using spring boot, then optionality in JSON would get determined at compile time. u can divide a player based on specialization and expose it on another rest endpoint `/player/specialization`

Comment: ^ that depends on you, if-else are wrong any day. instead, use a `Hash-Map`

Answer (score 0):

use a `Hash-Map`. use a `Validator` interface -> which can then have different implementations -> `BatsmanValidator` & `BowlerValidator`. You may also, abstract out the commonalities and validate them with one class like `PlayerValidator`.

#### Interface & Class

```
Interface Validator {
  public boolean validate(Player pojo);
}

class BatsmanValidator implements Validator {
  public boolean validate(Player pojo) {
  // code to validate a batsman 
  }
}
```

#### Usage

```
// setup validator
// Also, the player type should go in as enum.
Map<PlayerType, Validator> validators = new HashMap<>();
validators.put(Batsman, new BatsmanValidator());
validator.put(Bowler, new BowlerValidator());

// validate input
// This will itself validate the player based on type
// no if-else needed
validators.get(player.getType()).validate(player);
```

Comment: :Still in individual validators validate method, i will have to write mutiple if-else statements to check if the mandatory field values are given or not. Suppose, i also have to add business validations such as age > 0 and age < 100, country value is valid country name, wicketsTaken <=11 and maidenOvers <= oversBowled etc. Can we avoid multiple if else in this scenario.

Comment: u wiil have to use if-else somewhere to do the comparison. This avoids the mess of doing comparison in a single function.